# Methyl cellulose paste mixing mix-up

Tags: adhesives, origami, book-binding

I’m making MC (Methyl Cellulose) paste for origami, and it’s not mixing. When I stop stirring, all the MC just sinks. What am I doing wrong?
(If you need more info please comment, I’ve looked all over the web - no results. I’m using Lineco Pure MC.)

Comment: ok i may have solved it, but still, please, answer

Comment: Hi!, welcome to arts and crafts, can you please tell me what the process is called?

Comment: Even if you solved it, it would be useful if you could post an answer yourself, so you can help others out.

Comment: At what temperature did you mix the MC with water?

Answer (score 3):

Just put it in a watertight container and shake it. A lot.

Comment: It sounds like that eventually worked, but a couple of tricks may make it easier.  1. Start with hot water (~150F).  Sprinkle in the MC a little at a time, stirring continuously for many minutes to avoid clumps.  2. Let it sit for several hours, then stir again or put it in a shaker jar and shake.  It takes a while for the MC to absorb the water and gel.  People then often let it sit overnight before using it.